# Elasticsearch /all/ request

Tags: elasticsearch, request

Can somebody explain me please what exactly means **/all/** clause in request **indexName/all/_search**? It is request from old version ES2 but it is not compatible with ES6. If I understand it is the request to all **types** of documents in old version. So am I right if I remove /all/ from the request and get the same result via **indexName/_search**? Or is it not the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct, forget about all and simply use `indexName/_search`.

[Mapping types are going away](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html) anyway and there will only be a single implicit type per index as of ES 7.